# How does Quettra Portrait get the list of installed apps on non-jailbroken iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone

According to the [Quettra Portrait for iOS Privacy Policy](https://www.quettra.com/privacy/portrait-ios/) they manage to get a list of installed apps on iOS. What's more, they're able to do this from an App Store approved app on non-jailbroken devices. Every Google/StackOverflow search I've done on the matter suggests that this is impossible, but Quettra is somehow able to do it without raising the ire of Apple. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried contacting them and asking? I'd be interested to know as well.

Comment: This is their business USP, I doubt if they would tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the apps register a unique URL for deep linking purpose.

iOS has method `canOpenURL:` which tells you if a particular app is present or not on a user's device.

For example

facebook has fb://

Netflix has nflx://

Tripadvisor has tripadvisor://

Quettra has the list of these urls and makes several call to identify if a particular app is installed or not. By doing so, Quettra was able to establish interests of a user.

Earlier an app could make as many calls to `canOpenURL:` with different url parameters. 
Because companies were abusing this feature against user privacy interest, Apple has restricted 100 unique urls for `canOpenURL:`